# Users.threads: list in Gmail API not working with maxResults

Tags: php, multithreading, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

For some reason, the MaxResult in the Gmail API is not working and the result of the query gives me the whole list of threads in the mailbox.

Here is the code, do any one see the problem?

```
<?php
require_once '/path/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY,GMAIL_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $drive_service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  $threads = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $maxResults = 10;
  do {
    try {
      $opt_param = array();
      $opt_param['maxResults'] = $maxResults;
      if ($pageToken) {
        $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $threadsResponse = $drive_service->users_threads->listUsersThreads("mail@gmail.com", $opt_param);
      if ($threadsResponse->getThreads()) {
        $threads = array_merge($threads, $threadsResponse->getThreads());
        $pageToken = $threadsResponse->getNextPageToken();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);

  foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    print 'Thread with ID: ' . $thread->getId() . '<br/>';
  }

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, but your code loops until there is no `nextPageToken` present in the response. If you just want the first batch of 10 messages, ignore the loop:

```
$threads = array();
$maxResults = 10;

$opt_param = array();
$opt_param['maxResults'] = $maxResults;
$threadsResponse = $drive_service->users_threads->listUsersThreads("mail@gmail.com", $opt_param);

if ($threadsResponse->getThreads()) {
  $threads = array_merge($threads, $threadsResponse->getThreads());
}

foreach ($threads as $thread) {
  print 'Thread with ID: ' . $thread->getId() . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the maxResults you need is less than number of results returned per page by the API, which I believe is currently set at 100, then you can just remove the loop.

If you're trying to put a maximum limit on the number of result which is greater than the number returned per page (e.g. 1k max), so that the script doesn't run through thousands of emails (e.g. 20k), then the following may work for you.

```
 } while ($pageToken);
```

to

```
 } while ($pageToken && ($threads < $maxResults));
```